# using uielement.GetValue(), error "an object reference is required for the nonstatic field"

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I'm using the Bing maps API for Silverlight and need to cycle through a selection of pushpins on the map and perform some formatting if the pins name is not equal to a value elsewhere in the code.

Here is the function:

```
private void deselectAllPins(MapLayer mainMapLayer)
    {
        foreach (UIElement ui in mainMapLayer.Children)
            if (ui is SitePushpin)
            {
                SolidColorBrush scb = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);

                if (ui.GetValue(SitePushpin.SiteName).ToString() != hiddenShortName.Text)
                {
                    ....formatting
                }
            }
    }
```

The 'SitePushpin' is declared as:

```
public class SitePushpin : Pushpin
{
    public string SiteName { get; set; }
    public SitePushpin(Color Bg)
    {
        this.Name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        SolidColorBrush scb = new SolidColorBrush(Bg);
        this.Background = scb;
    }
}
```

My issue comes in at the if statement with the ui.GetValue.  It is unable to see the SiteName attribute and comes up with the error

> "an object reference is required for the nonstatic field"

Any ideas how I can get it to see this value?

Many thanks
Cap

Comment: It looks like you are using variable names for the property access. Is that correct, or did you mean to access a property named SiteName by a Dependency Property? The "answer" below may compile (not sure how as SiteName is not a DP), but the actual code does not make sense to me (yet). Can you clarify at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Property `SiteName` is an instance property, not a `type/static` so you should have instance of the `SitePushpin` class and then access `SiteName` property.

SO

```cs
var pushpin = ui as SitePushpin;
if (pushpin != null)
{
     SolidColorBrush scb = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red); 
     if (ui.GetValue(pushpin.SiteName).ToString() != hiddenShortName.Text)                                 
     {
        ....formatting                 
     } 
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Change this:

```
if (ui.GetValue(SitePushpin.SiteName).ToString()
```

to this:

```
if (ui.GetValue(ui.SiteName).ToString()
```

or even this:

```
if (ui.SiteName != hiddenShortName.Text)
```

Comment: it just check whether object is of specific type but not cast it